# Why is this list becoming NoneType when a recursion happens?

Tags: python, function, recursion, nonetype

so im trying to make this code which finds if there is a subset of numbers in a list which sum up to a result which is also passed in. Whenever I run my code however for some reason my currentlist variable becomes NoneType. This is the error I get:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

This is my code:

```
def resultinSubset(t,s):
    currentlist=[]
    currentsum=0
    def recresultinSubset(t,s,i,currentsum,currentlist):
        if currentsum == t:
            return True
        if i == (len(s)):
            return False
        newlist=currentlist.append(s[i])
        newsum=int(currentsum)+int(s[i])
        including=recresultinSubset(t,s,i+1,newsum,newlist)
        notincl=recresultinSubset(t,s,i+1,currentsum,currentlist)
        return including + notincl
    return recresultinSubset(t,s,0,currentsum,currentlist)
    print(currentlist)                                  
print(resultinSubset(6, [1,2,3]))
```

Comment: Please *always* try to provide a [mcve]. If you are getting an error, post the entire error message including the stack trace. The following line: `newlist=currentlist.append(s[i])` assigns `None` to `newlist`, because `.append` *returns `None`*. Note, `.append` does not create a new list. This has nothing to do with recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newlist=currentlist.append(s[i])
```

This sets `newlist = None` since `append()` doesn't have a return value. If you want a new list with an extra value appended use:

```
newlist = currentlist + [s[i]]
```

Note that creating a new list every recursive call is quite inefficient. It'd be worth modifying the algorithm to manipulate a single list in place.

Comment: I've just figured it out but thank you !